# Fingerprint enrollment works on Ubuntu 20.04, but unable to unlock with fingerprint

Tags: login, 20.04, fingerprint-reader

After successfully enabling Fingerprint Login on my user and enrolling my thumb, I lock the screen and try to unlock it with my thumb but nothing happens. Rebooting the system didn't help. Looking at the logs I found this line in `/var/log/auth.log`:

> gdm-fingerprint]: gkr-pam: no password is available for user

Although I have a password set on my user.

My laptop is Asus UX430UNR, and the fingerprint reader is:

> 04f3:0903 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just resolved a problem that looked the same. The actual problem was that I didn't know how to swipe.

Check if you can swipe with `$fprintd-enroll` and then `$fprintd-verify` (in the terminal emulator). 
If you can't pass, see [here](https://github.com/iafilatov/libfprint#common-problems). TL;DR one should swipe carefully from the finger base to the tip, both in the configuration and the verification.

Comment: Apparently I was swiping a smaller than necessary portion of my finger, during both enrollment and verification. Thanks.

Comment: Enrollement works every time but verification and login NEVER ;-(